# Safe path.resolve without escaping from parent

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing an (expressjs) http service, which gets a relative path as user input on every call, reads a file from the filesystem based on that path, and processes it, like:

```
app.get("/api", (req, res, next) => {
    var filePath = path.resolve("./datasource", req.query.path);
    fs.readFile(filePath, "utf8", (err, data) => {
        processData(data, (err, processed) => {
            res.json(processed);
        });
    });
});
```

I stripped out error handling for clarity. The problem with this is that one could call the url `/api?path=../../../etc/passwd`, and that would leak information from the server itself. I would like this api not to process files outside of the `./datasource` folder. I think I could use some customized implementation of `path.resolve`, which does not escape the parent, but it looks like to me there is no such functionality in the `path` module. Some examples I thought of:

```
saferesolve("./datasource", "a/b") === "./datasource/a/b"
saferesolve("./datasource", "a/b/../c") === "./datasource/a/c"
saferesolve("./datasource", "../..") === "./datasource"
saferesolve("./datasource", "../../a/b") === "./datasource/a/b"
saferesolve("./datasource", "../../a/b/..") === "./datasource/a"
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this without reinventing the whole `path` module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to pass your tests:

```
function saferesolve(base, target) {
  var targetPath = '.' + path.posix.normalize('/' + target)
  return path.posix.resolve(base, targetPath)
}
```

Comment: I feel good about this approach, but doesn't work on windows. Maybe using `path.posix.resolve` would be better.

Comment: @TamasHegedus I updated my answer to add the `.posix` bit into each `path` method call, but I don't have access to a Windows computer so could you let me know what the output is for you? I'm just curious what is happening.

Comment: Great, thanks, I think that's what I was searching for!